# Programmatically get a Type's Alias in .NET

Tags: reflection

Is it possible to determine an object type's **alias(es)** through reflection? Given the following example where **myObject** is of type System.Int32 -- e.g

```
Type t = myObject.GetType();
```

**t.Name** will be **Int32**.  However, I would like to identify the possibile alias(es), if any, of the objects in question, so that I could resolve the type name of **int** *in addition to* **Int32**

I'm not looking to spend a huge amount of time on this.  If there isn't an extreamely simple, built in solution, I'll just map the values myself. =)

Comment: int does not exist as a .net type at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly with reflection, there is not.  The "type name" (as you are calling it) "int" is not a type name at all, but a language keyword.

You could, of course, use a dictionary to store the look ups from type names to the shorter convenience forms.  But there is nothing in the reflection API's that will do that for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can get language specific type alias by using CodeDom classes

```
    var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var vb = new VBCodeProvider();

    var type = typeof (int);
    Console.WriteLine("Type Name: {0}", type.Name); // Int32
    Console.WriteLine("C# Type Name: {0}", cs.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type))); // int
    Console.WriteLine("VB Type Name: {0}", vb.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type))); // Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The aliases appear to be compile-time only.  Notice how they don't apply outside of a given source file.  They are simply conveniences, nothing more.